# Illegal static declaration

Tags: java, swing

Hello I am currently receiving an error with my code, this is the error 'Illegal static declaration in inner class Main.Test
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations' I have searched around here and I sort of understand why this error has occurred but I cannot figure out specifically what I need to change, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! - I have tried to make my other class static as I saw in some other post but this still did not work

here is my code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
public Main() {
    String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Projects Design");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    String text = username;
    JTextArea textAreal = new JTextArea(text, 10, 10);
    textAreal.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    textAreal.setLineWrap(true);
    textAreal.setEditable(false);
    frame.add(textAreal);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

   public class Test extends JFrame{
   JComboBox jc = new JComboBox();
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   Connection con;
   Statement st;
   ResultSet rs;
   public Test() {
       this.setSize(400, 400);
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       try{
       con = DriverManager.getConnection("Removed for obvious   reasons");
       st = con.createStatement();
       String s = "SELECT Code FROM users WHERE id="12";
       rs = st.executeQuery(s);
       while(rs.next())
       {
           jc.addItem(rs.getString(1));
       }
       }catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR");
       }finally{
       try{
       st.close();
       rs.close();
       con.close();
       }catch(Exception e){  
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR CLOSE");  
       }
       }
       panel.add(jc);
       this.getContentPane().add(panel);
       this.setVisible(true);

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Main rectProg = new Main();
    new Test();
    }
```

Comment: Yeh I already looked at this post you have just linked and this did not work for me, so I wasn't sure what else I could of done.

Answer (score -1):

Ah I figured it out, I moved my static class outside of my inner class as I had a static method inside of an inner class! Thanks for help